# "Events type" in java

Tags: swing, events, user-interface, java

My program contain two classes, one represent the main program and the other one is a gui implemented using swing,

I'm trying to create an "event type", meaning I want my main program to wait until the UserInterface (GUI) will indicate some event, like pressing a button, and I would like to sends some information when my button is pressed.

General Code for the main program (this is the relevant section)

```
// Open window GUI with the requested BID and wait for confirmation or denial

HumanIFWindow nextWindowGUI = new HumanIFWindow();
nextWindowGUI.setVisible(true);

// ----------------- //     
// - Wait on event - //
// ----------------- //
// Here is where I want to wait for the gui Indication

return returnedBid;
```

Code for the GUI (Again only relevant part)

```
JButton btnAprove = new JButton("Aprove");
btnAprove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

// ----------------- //
// - Trigger event - //
// ----------------- //
// Here is where I want to trigger the event

}});
```

Preferably I would like to use some library, is there's one that match my needs? 
(Maybe BusEvent?)

**Edit to specify the question (Thanks  Kishan Sarsecha Gajjar)**

I want the first class (the general one) to enter a wait statement, I know how to wait using:

```
while( someBoolean...)
Thread.sleep(...)
```

and I can change someBoolean with a handle in the GUI class, Like:

```
FisrtClass.someBoolean == False
```

But I want something nicer and neater, like a library that Implements the sleep statement. and there's no additional code needed. Is there something like that?
I've looked at Google-BusEvent library but I'm not sure if that's compatible

**EDIT, adding JDialog**

updated code: Main program:

```
Bid returnedBid = requestBid;
// Open window GUI with the requested BID and wait for confirmation

DialogHumanConfirmManual nextWindowGUI = new DialogHumanConfirmManual(requestBid);

// Wait on event
if ( (returnedBid = nextWindowGUI.getAnswer()) != null ){
System.out.println("Got Bid " + returnedBid.print());
}
```

GUI - Dialog:

```
public DialogHumanConfirmManual(Bid requestedBid){

    currentBid = requestedBid;
    currentBid.approvedHuman = false;
    Dialog mainFrame = new Dialog(new Frame());

    myPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(myPanel);
    myPanel.add(new JLabel("Confirmation Dialog"));

    yesButton = new JButton("Confirm");
    yesButton.addActionListener(this);
    myPanel.add(yesButton); 

    noButton = new JButton("No");
    noButton.addActionListener(this);
    myPanel.add(noButton);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);       


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (yesButton == e.getSource()) {
        currentBid.approvedHuman = true;
        answeredBid = currentBid;

    }


}
```

After opening the Dialog the if ( returnBid ) is called, which result in Null Pointer Exception later on in the code, So How can I delay the main program until the user can Confirm the request??

Comment: Flagged : Question is too broad...

Comment: The best solution for your specific situation is to use a modal JDialog as camickr notes in his answer (1+ to him), or if you're dead set against using that -- and you should probably justify your reasoning for this, then use any one of a number of listener/observer interfaces. The latter could be via a PropertyChangeSupport -- note that this is already inherent in Swing components, or even allowing outside classes to add ActionListener to a key JButton. Again, I favor camickr's answer but have used both in different situations.

Comment: while using JDialog I'll still need to Implement the **While(..) sleep method**, I wanted a way around it. for example, pressing the Jdialog's OK button will trigger an event that the mail program will simply wait on, when the event is triggered the main program will continue

Answer (score 3):

> the other one is a gui implemented using swing,

Use a `modal JDialog` not a JFrame.

Once the dialog is made visible, the code after the setVisible(true) statement will NOT execute until the dialog is closed.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information. The tutorial covers the JOptionPane class, but you can just use a JDialog, which is created exactly the same way a JFrame is. You can choose whether to use a JOptionPane or JDialog depending on your exact requirement.